# Spring boot JNDI datasource lookup failure

Tags: java, spring-boot, deployment, centos7, tomcat8

I'm trying to deploy an existing (Angular+Spring Boot)app on Centos 7 using tomcat 8.5 which use JNDI 
but I'm getting those errors in the catalina.out log :

```
25-Apr-2020 14:50:25.294 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement   No rules found matching 'Server/GlobalNamingResources/Context/Resource'.
```

```
25-Apr-2020 14:50:27.251 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/ODT.xml]
25-Apr-2020 14:50:27.538 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor A docBase [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ODTBACK] inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored
25-Apr-2020 14:50:27.611 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'autoDeploy' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
25-Apr-2020 14:50:29.742 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
25-Apr-2020 14:50:30.027 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/ODT.xml] has finished in [2,775] ms
25-Apr-2020 14:50:30.043 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/ODTBACK.xml]
25-Apr-2020 14:50:30.045 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor A docBase [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ODTBACK] inside the host appBase has been specified, and will be ignored
25-Apr-2020 14:50:30.050 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'autoDeploy' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
25-Apr-2020 14:50:53.054 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
```

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'utilisateurRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IUtilisateurRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#15d50eaa' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#15d50eaa': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6d61be4f]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [ma/enova/odt/common/config/JNDIDataSourceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'jdbc/odt'; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/odt] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5156) [catalina.jar:8.5.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:8.5.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743) [catalina.jar:8.5.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719) [catalina.jar:8.5.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705) [catalina.jar:8.5.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:614) [catalina.jar:8.5.53]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1823) [catalina.jar:8.5.53]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_242]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'utilisateurRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IUtilisateurRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#15d50eaa' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#15d50eaa': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6d61be4f]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [ma/enova/odt/common/config/JNDIDataSourceConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.DataSourceLookupFailureException: Failed to look up JNDI DataSource with name 'jdbc/odt'; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/odt] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
```

I added to web.xml

```
  ...
  <resource-ref>
    <description>JNDI Lookup</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/odt</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->

<!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application -->

<Context>

    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>
  <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
  -->

</Context>
  <!--  
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/odt"
             global="jdbc/odt"
             auth="Container"
             type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
  -->
```

server.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8585" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->

        <Context>
            <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved"    
            factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" 
            type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
        <Resource name="jdbc/odt" 
            auth="Container"
                type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
            driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
                    url="jdbc:postgresql://172.16.30.35:5432/odt"
                username="postgres" 
            password="admin" 
            maxTotal="20" 
            maxIdle="10"
                maxWaitMillis="-1"/>
    </Context>
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8585" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8585" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define an SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation. The default
         SSLImplementation will depend on the presence of the APR/native
         library and the useOpenSSL attribute of the
         AprLifecycleListener.
         Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used regardless of
         the SSLImplementation selected. JSSE style configuration is used below.
    -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
    -->
    <!-- Define an SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 with HTTP/2
         This connector uses the APR/native implementation which always uses
         OpenSSL for TLS.
         Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used. OpenSSL style
         configuration is used below.
    -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/localhost-rsa-key.pem"
                         certificateFile="conf/localhost-rsa-cert.pem"
                         certificateChainFile="conf/localhost-rsa-chain.pem"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <!--
    <Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
               address="::1"
               port="8009"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->

    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" 
    unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <!--
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
    <Context>
        <Resource name="jdbc/odt" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username="postgres"
          password="admin"
          driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
          url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/odt"
          maxTotal="25"
          maxIdle="10"
          validationQuery="select 1" /> 
    </Context>
    -->
        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

i also created xml file in /opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/ODT.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->

<!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application -->
<!--
<Context>

    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>
  <Manager pathname="" />


</Context>
-->
<Context docBase="ODTBACK" path="/ODTBACK" reloadable="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <ResourceLink global="jdbc/odt" name="jdbc/odt" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
    <Resources cachingAllowed="false" />
    <Resource
            name="jdbc/odt"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            username="postgres"
            password="admin"
            driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://172.16.30.35:5432/odt"
            maxActive="8"
            maxIdle="4"
        validationQuery="select 1"
    />
</Context>
```

here's the spring boot code for looking the datasource

```
package ma.enova.odt.common.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup;

@Configuration
@Profile({ "dev", "test", "prod" , "recette" , "preprod" })
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public class JNDIDataSourceConfig {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.jndi-name}")
    private String JNDI_NAME;
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() 
    {
      JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
      return dataSourceLookup.getDataSource(JNDI_NAME);
    }
}
```

tried some links but no success :
[Failed to look up JNDI DataSource using Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177566/failed-to-look-up-jndi-datasource-using-spring-boot)
[Failed to look up JNDI DataSource In Spring Boot Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100891/failed-to-look-up-jndi-datasource-in-spring-boot-application)
[SEVERE: Exception looking up UserDatabase under key UserDatabase javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [UserDatabase] is not bound in this Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41630337/severe-exception-looking-up-userdatabase-under-key-userdatabase-javax-naming-na)

Can you please tell me what i'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: did you resolve this?

Comment: hi sorry for the delay in centos 7 no but it worked in windows